# How to upscale an image so that the result is not blurry or black?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scaling, scikit-image

I'm using the following code in order to upscale an image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize

image = np.array(
    [[[51, 153, 255],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [51, 255, 51]]]
)

# image2 = rescale(image, 40.0, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True).astype(np.int) # produces a black image
image2 = rescale(image, 40.0, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True) # produces a black image
# image2 = resize(image, (255, 255, 3)) # produces a black image

print(image2)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()
```

However, this is not working as expected, as `image2` becomes black. I really want to produce a new array, because I will be saving this array as an image to the file system. Specifically, I will create a gif animation from the upscaled version of these arrays. However, I want to create an upscaled version that is **not** blurry, but like the original, as you can see when you `imshow(image)` above, i.e.

[image]

I guess I am using the API incorrectly and, meanwhile, maybe I will figure out the right way of doing what I want.

Comment: Hi, 

You might want to look into `interpolate` option in the imshow function.

Comment: @rponthieudev Well, my ultimate goal is not only to show the images, but also to save these arrays as images (png files, e.g.) to the file system.

Comment: Yup, sorry I went too fast, I think the probleme comes from the fact that it as trouble to work on the 3 channels. I would work on R,G and B separately and then fuse them. Working on that I tell you if I find a neat solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way of doing what I want with pillow's `Image.resize` method. Here's an example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = np.array(
    [[[51, 153, 255],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [51, 255, 51]]]
    , dtype=np.uint8) # np.uint8 this is important!

upscaled_image = Image.fromarray(image).resize([300, 300], resample=Image.NEAREST)
upscaled_image = np.asarray(upscaled_image)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(upscaled_image)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I made your exemple work by dividing the image by 255 (tested in python3).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize

image = np.array(
    [[[51, 153, 255],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224]],

     [[224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [224, 224, 224],
      [51, 255, 51]]]
)

# image2 = rescale(image, 40.0, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True).astype(np.int) # produces a black image
image2 = rescale(image/255, 40.0, anti_aliasing=True, multichannel=True) # produces a black image
# image2 = resize(image, (255, 255, 3)) # produces a black image

print(image2)

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()
```

Looks like skimage has problem with integer images.

Best,
R